# Microsft SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 giving debugging error

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have created small SSIS project in SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015. While debugging the project I am getting below error.

> Unable To Start debugging.
>   The Debugger is not properly installed
>   Run setup to install or repair the debugger. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration).

[image]

Comment: Just to make this issue clearly, whether other project still has this issue like a simple C# console app? Which SSDT version did you install? Please install the latest update for your VS IDE, and make sure that the process was running in your task manager. The reason why we need to know that whether all projects has this issue is that we have to know that whether it is related to the specific project itself or the whole VS debugging Environment. Of course, please repair your VS if all project has this issue, and then restart your VS, create a new one, debug it again.

Comment: Hi Jay, did you manage to get to the bottom of this issue? I am having the same issue with VS 2017 and was wondering if I could get any pointers for resolving this.