# SQL Server Data Tools 2017 for Visual Studio 2017 - Unable to start debugger error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I'm having trouble with the debugger when trying to run a simple SSIS project involving importing a small sample CSV file into SQL Server.

I have searched StackOverflow with "debugger error Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration" and looked at all the search results.

It looks like someone else had the same issue with VS2015 about a year ago, but it never got resolved.

[Microsft SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 giving debugging error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447230/microsft-sql-server-data-tools-for-visual-studio-2015-giving-debugging-error)

I've tried looking at the Event Viewer and generated Visual Studio Logs but there's nothing there.

I get 2 error messages when I try to execute the SSIS job.

Error 1:

```
Unable to start debugging.
The debugger is not properly installed.
Run setup to install or repair the debugger. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Program Location:

   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(IVsDebugger iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchActivePackage(Int32 launchOptions)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
```

Error 2:

```
Unable to start program 'DTS'.

The debugger is not properly installed.  Cannot debug the requested type of code.  Run setup to install or repair the debugger. (Microsoft Visual Studio Debugger)

Program Location:

   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(IVsDebugger iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
```

I had a lot of trouble getting SSDT installed and working with Visual Studio 2017 and had to resort to the solution here to get it working.

[SSDT installation issue (Failed to execute EXE package.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package)

Has anyone come across this issue and manage to overcome it?

In the meantime, I will try reinstalling the packages in the payload folder and see if that will fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like it's an ongoing issue as outlined here.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f858d6c1-6991-4c2f-b4ae-4155d6944bff/error-in-visual-studio-2017-integration-services-project-unable-to-start-debugging-the-debugger-is?forum=vssetup

Comment: I have installed SSDT for VS2015 and I have a workaround using VS2015 for now.

Comment: I am facing same issue for VS 2017 and still not able to resolve

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati, there's a thread here that indicates it's a wide spread problem affecting many VS 2017 users.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f858d6c1-6991-4c2f-b4ae-4155d6944bff/error-in-visual-studio-2017-integration-services-project-unable-to-start-debugging-the-debugger-is?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 2):

#### Excuse my necromancy

I know this is an old-ish question, but there are still enough people out there that haven't transitioned to VS 2019 yet for it to be relevant. I ran into this problem again for the second time, but it was a very long time in between occurrences. I completely forgot what the issue and solutions were.

## Long answer

I have documented it all [here](http://obscureproblemsandgotchas.com/development/sql-server/visual-studio-2017-ssis-unable-to-start-debugging/).

## Short answer

Here is the short version of what I documented:

1. Don't rush to uninstall/reinstall Visual Studio 2017
2. Very carefully read the blue box on the [VS 2017 SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer) download page. This is *critical*.
3. Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2017
4. Run the installer and pay attention to the installer to see if it warns you about older extensions or installers that may exist already. Follow the instructions provided.
5. Assuming you have this problem, close the installer.
6. Uninstall the Visual Studio SSIS, SSRS and SSAS extensions (VSIX)
7. Run the SSDT installer - make sure it is warning free
8. Proceed with the installation
9. This should work and solve the problem, but this is a complex issue so I cannot make a guarantee. This has worked for me twice now on two entirely separate machines (work and home).

Comment: I'm still alive, so your necromancy is officially excused. Jokes aside, great documentation of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did able to solve the issue with SQL server 2016 and Visual studio 2015 and respective SSDT 2015. I made sure I install every time as administrator (Right click on EXE and Run as Administrator).

I followed these steps:

1. I uninstalled all SQL Server Management Studio, SQL Server 2017, Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT.
2. Deleted the folders

   ```
    C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
    C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   ```
3. Installed SQL Server 2016 (as administrator)
4. Installed SQL Server Management Studio latest version (as administrator)
5. Installed Visual Studio 2015 (for me VS 2015 gave some missing DLL and I did repair - it started working fine)
6. Finally I installed Visual Studio Data Tools for 2015.

Please find the exes for installing VS2015, SSDT-2015 and SQL Server 2016 from [here](https://github.com/satishakumar/SSIS) and you can also download them from official sites through search.

and SSMS from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

I hope this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by filling in the required fields in the Execute SQL Task.  I was missing the value in the SQL Statement field.

The other way I got rid of this error is to set the "DelayValidation" property from False to True.  But that is only a workaround until you fix the real issue.

This page was also helpful.

http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/07/ssis-package-taking-forever-to-load-when-you-open-it/

DelayValidation <-- find this property in Control Flow tasks

ValidateExternalMetadata <-- find this property in Data Flow tasks

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS2019 for SSIS. Just go to Debug and use option: start without debugging.

If you have to see the error where it gets failed then read logs coming in command prompt.